# formatting GQL query

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I am trying to implement this example in my app:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

I keep getting an error that says:
BadQueryError: Parse Error: "IS" can only be used when comparing against "ANCESTOR" at symbol :1

which refers to this line in my code:

```
result = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Image WHERE ANCESTER IS :1", get_gallery_key())
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANCESTOR is misspelled in the query.

Comment: that makes sense ... [kicks self]